# GA cookie data passed cross-domain from a form submission?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, cookie, goal-tracking

Hello fellow webmasters,

So I have successfully set up cross domain tracking using tag manager and getting the unique clientId cookie data to be passed via URL parameter and seeing users convert in a funnel, fun stuff!

I have to implement this to a few sites, first of all, the site I got this working on referred to the second domain name with a regular `<a>` link.

Here is the tricky part where one of you might be able to help. The other sites I'm implementing this in have opt-in forms which after you submit then refer you to the second domain using InfusionSoft's email system. Because of this, Google's tag manager is not passing the _GA cookie data in the URL therefore creating a brand new session. Which causes my goal funnel to not convert through the steps.

Any idea or input on how this could be solved simply, without creating a second landing page after opt-in with a button telling users to click?

Comment: My current workaround uses UTM tracking URL parameters in the redirect url which the form uses in order to track users who optin. Though ideally I would like to put these pages in a goal funnel so everything stays organized. But that requires passing the cookie data so google does not create a new session.

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager has an option to "decorate forms". You can find it under your pageview tag: `More Settings` -> `Cross Domain Tracking` -> `Decorate Forms`. Set that to true and GTM will send the GA cookie along to **where the form submits to**. If you have additional redirects after that, it'll be more difficult. What do you mean by this:

> after you submit then refer you to the second domain using InfusionSoft's email system

Does the form submit launch an email client? If it is just a contact form that submits to the secondary domain (while also sending the email), the `Decorate Forms` option should work fine. Just make sure that the usual suspects `Referral Exclusion List -> Add secondary domain` and GTM's `Auto Link Domains -> secondary domain` are taken care of.